# Deleting windows displaying buffer

Tags: emacs, window, buffer

I would like to modify this function to detach a buffer to a new frame.  And
deleting any window displaying the buffer in the old frame.

```
(defun detach-window ()
  "Sends the selected window to a new frame."

  (interactive)

  (let* ( (window (selected-window))
          (buf (window-buffer window))
          (frame (make-frame)) )

    (select-frame frame)
    (switch-to-buffer buf)
    (delete-window window)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  "Tear off window and delete others showing buffer.
Delete all windows from selected frame that show buffer of
selected window, and show the buffer in a new frame."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf  (window-buffer (selected-window)))
        win)
    ;; If all windows in selected frame show BUF, then handle error
    ;; "Attempt to delete minibuffer or sole ordinary window", by
    ;; replacing BUF with`other-buffer` in the last window showing BUF.
    (condition-case nil
        (while (setq win  (get-buffer-window buf)) (delete-window win))
      (error (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer buf))))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-frame buf)))
```

Comment: I have tried it, but the buffer is still in old frame.

Comment: What's your recipe for that?

Comment: I run an emacs session and load a file. Then call foo. The new frame with a copy of the buffer is made. But although I do not see the old window in the old frame, I am still able to see it in the menu Buffers. The file is still there.

Comment: **Of course the buffer is still in menu `Buffers`!** It still exists. Your question doesn't say anything about killing the buffer. By now you should the difference between a window and a buffer. And no, don't change the question. If you have a different question, ask it separately. But I think you know how to kill a buffer, right?

Comment: Right, because I wrote window.  I know the difference, but I ended up writing window. `(kill-buffer buffer)`.